# jQuery: How to assign the right ID to a button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS/jQuery script that adds our leads (web contacts) to the DOM in a for loop.  Everything works fine except for one thing.  I want the body of the lead to be hidden upon the initial display, and then have a slideToggle button to display or hide the details  That means dynamically adding click events to each button as it is created.  The entire HTML (HTML and a JSON object mixed into the HTML) of the lead and the slideToggle button are all appended to a node in the DOM in the for loop.  Here is the pertinent part of the for loop:

```
// Hide the body of the lead; just show the title bar and the first line
var dataID = data[i].id
var div = $('#row' + dataID);
var more = $('#more' + dataID);

div.hide();

// Create click event for each "+" button
more.click(function() {
     div.slideToggle();
});
```

But when I click on the "+" button to reveal the details, it opens the last div, not the div I am trying to open.  This is true no matter how many leads I have on the page.  How do I get the click event to open the right div.  If I console.log "div" in the click event, it gives me the ID of the last div, not the one I am clicking on.  But if I console.log(div) outside the click event, it has the right ID.

Also, I was unsure whether I needed the "vars" in the loop or if I should declare them outside the loop.

Here is the HTML.  It's one lead plus the beginning of the next lead, which I left closed in Firebug

```
<div id="lead1115">
<div id="learnmore">
<a id="more1115" class="more" href="#">+</a>
</div>
<div id="lead-info">
<div id="leadID">Lead ID# Date: March 27, 2012 11:26 AM (Arizona time)</div>
<div id="company">No company given</div>
<div id="name">Meaghan Dee</div>
<div id="email">
<a href="mailto:meaghan.dee@gmail.com">meaghan.dee@gmail.com</a>
</div>
<br class="clearall">
<div>
<div id="row1115" style="display: none;">
<div id="phone">No phone given</div>
<div id="source">www.ulsinc.com/misc/expert-contact/</div>
<div id="cp-name">No channel partner chosen</div>
<br class="clearall">
<div id="location">
No location given
<br>
<strong>IP Address:</strong>
198.82.10.87
<br>
<span>Approximate Location: Blacksburg, Virginia, United States</span>
<br>
</div>
<div id="details">
<strong>Questions/Comments</strong>
<br>
We have the Professional Series Universal Laser Systems (laser cutter), and I wondered how I would order a high power density 2.0 replacement lens.nnThank you
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="learnmore">
<a id="1115|send_message" class="verify" href="#">Verify</a>
<a id="1115|send_message" class="markAsSpam" href="#">Spam</a>
<a id="1115|send_message" class="markAsDuplicate" href="#">Duplicate</a>
</div>
</div>
<br class="clearall">
<div id="lead1116">
<br class="clearall">
```

Comment: More HTML, please. But I suspect something like `$(this).closest('.container').find('.row').slideToggle()` will do the trick.

Comment: Or a jsfiddle would be really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.bind` (or `.on` for 1.7+) and the data parameter.

```
more.bind("click",{target:div},function(e){
    e.data.target.show();
}
```

or

```
more.on("click",{target:div},function(e){
    e.data.target.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin.  That worked.  And thanks for reminding me to get in the habit of using "on".  You rock!

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic problem is that `div` is common as a variable to all items. You have to separate the div's from each other by, for example, creating a local function and call it for each item. Something like:

```
function buildMore(div) {
    more.click(function() {
        div.slideToggle();
    });
}
```

and in the loop call:

```
addMore(div);
```

**p.s.**
Whether you declare your variables inside or outside the loop doesn't matter: you still get the same variables.

Answer (score 0):

The variable div doesn't stay frozen with your click handler so it's value will be what it was at the end of the for loop and all click handlers will use the same value (which is what you're seeing).

There are a number of different ways to approach this and I thought all would be educational.  Any one of them should work.

### Idea #1 - Manufacture the row id from the clicked on more id

Use the id value on the clicked on link to manufacture the matching row ID.  Since you create them in pairs, this can be done programmatically like this:

```
// Hide the body of the lead; just show the title bar and the first line
var dataID = data[i].id
$('#row' + dataID).hide();
$('#more' + dataID).click(function() {
     // manufacture the row ID value from the clicked on id
     var id = this.id.replace("more", "#row");
     $(id).slideToggle();
});
```

### Idea #2 - Use a function closure to "freeze" the values you want

Another way to do that is to create a function and closure that will capture the current value of div:

```
// Hide the body of the lead; just show the title bar and the first line
var dataID = data[i].id
var div = $('#row' + dataID).hide();
var more = $('#more' + dataID);

function addClick(moreItem, divItem) {
    // Create click event for each "+" button
    moreItem.click(function() {
         divItem.slideToggle();
    });
}

addClick(more, div);
```

### Idea #3 - Use the HTML spatial relationship to find the row associated with a more

To make this work, you need to put a common `class=lead` on the top level lead div like this:

```
<div id="lead1115" class="lead">
```

And, a common class on each row:

```
<div id="row1115" class="row" style="display: none;">
```

Then, you can use the position relationships to find the row object that is in the same parent lead object as the clicked on more link like this:

```
// Hide the body of the lead; just show the title bar and the first line
var dataID = data[i].id
$('#row' + dataID).hide();
$('#more' + dataID).click(function() {
     // find out common parent, then find the row in that common parent
     $(this).closest(".lead").find(".row").slideToggle();
});
```

### Idea #4 - Put the row ID as data on the more link

```
// Hide the body of the lead; just show the title bar and the first line
var dataID = data[i].id
$('#row' + dataID).hide();
$('#more' + dataID).data("row", "#row" + dataID).click(function() {
     // get the corresponding row from the data on the clicked link
     var rowID = $(this).data("row");
     $(rowID).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because div variable gets changed and settles with the last value set in the loop.
Try this:

```
...
funciton createClick(div) {
 return function() { div.slidToggle();
}
more.click( createClick(div) );
...
```